# How to get URL link of search result page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Anyone know how can I get a URL link that directs the user to the search result page as if I typed my candidate number into the form and hit search?

https://www.axelos.com/successful-candidates-register

Answer (score 0):

This web page uses [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) to get the data when you submit the form. It does not redirect to a new URL. So, in short, there's no URL.

You can try querying the API to get the candidate data which *does* have a specific URL pattern: `https://fa-axelos-prod-ukw.azurewebsites.net/api/scr/?first_name={first_name}&surname={surname}&candidate_number={candidate_number}&numberPerPage=20&offset=0`

(Replace the variables in between `{}` with values of your choice.)

Example: `https://fa-axelos-prod-ukw.azurewebsites.net/api/scr/?first_name=John&surname=Doe&candidate_number=213123&numberPerPage=20&offset=0`

In this example I used `John` as `first_name`, `Smith` as `surname` and `213123` as `candidate_number`.

NOTE: you cannot share the URL of the API in order to recreate the page with those values, as you would with a normal URL.